# While rotating device a onActivityCreated() of previous class is always called

Tags: android

I am new to android.I have one problem.I am using fragments.My application has 5 tabs.My application stopped unexpectedly after one particular tab then moves to another tab and rotates the current view.By debugging I got the error.Error is that while rotating current view control goes to onActivtyCreated() of previous class.

> datetext.setText(TimeFormater.FormatDate(dateString));

This line gives the null pointer exception.Control always goes to the code given below.

```
public class ScheduleDailyView extends SherlockFragment{public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    nextbutn = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.buttonnext);
    prebutn = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.buttonpre);
    listview = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lv_schedule_listView);
    datetext = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textscheduleviewdate);
    dateString = TimeFormater.DateToString(Schedule.currentDate.getTime());
    ArrayList<ViewScheduleDTO> scheduleList =scheduleDaily.readschedules(dateString,doctor_id);
    datetext.setText(TimeFormater.FormatDate(dateString));
    rowitems = scheduleDaily.getScheduleRowList(dateString,scheduleList);
    listview.setAdapter(new ScheduleCustomView(appContext, rowitems));
    if(userType.equals(UserTypeEnum.Admin.getDisplayName()) || userType.equals(UserTypeEnum.Doctor.getDisplayName()))
        listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    nextbutn.setOnClickListener(this);
    prebutn.setOnClickListener(this);
}}
```

Comment: Are you sure datetext exist in the layout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... add this line in your manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="Your Activity Name"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever device screen is rotated the present activity is recreated. In which orientation you want your application to be.. You can fix it in by declaring it in manifest file.... If it is in both orientations the go through the following link :

[Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Hope this will help you....

Comment: But my problem is control goes to previously executed activity

Comment: I think your present activity is getting destroyed on orientation change and the activity comes up from activitystack

Comment: Ya,Solved it by adding android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to manifest.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the orientation in Manifest.xml file. Changing from portrait to landscape or vice versa might help.